# "En nombre de quién" o "A nombre de quién"

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

Cuál preposición hay que usar cuando estás de viaje, hablas con una recepcionista en un hotel sobre tu reserva en hotel - esta reserva está "a" nombre de o "en" nombre de alguien?

En un curso de español Mi Vida Loca (http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/spanish/mividaloca/) vi un siguiente diálogo en un hotel en España:

*Cliente - "Tengo una reserva."* (o algo así, pero con el mismo significado)

*Recepcionista - "**En** nombre de quién?*"

Pero de una película "Contratiempo" (también España) las siguientes oraciones:

"*La matrícula del vehículo que conducía esta mujer pertenece a un BMW que está **a** nombre de su cliente.*"

*Cliente: "Tengo una reserva. Habitación 715, por favor.*"

*Recepcionista: "-Sí. ¿**A** nombre de Adrián Doria?*"

P.S. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tu pregunta tiene cierta relación con [la que se plantea aquí](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151919/reservation-under-the-name-in-the-name-or-by-the-name-of-ms-x) en nuestro foro hermano en relación a esa misma situación pero en inglés.

Desde mi punto de vista, la expresión idiomática sería "**a nombre de**".

"**En nombre de**" se emplea cuando un persona hace de "proxy" respecto a otra, es decir, imagínate que llega un paquete a tu casa **a nombre de** tu padre, es el nombre de tu padre el que figura en la etiqueta, y tú lo aceptas **en su nombre** porque él no está en ese momento.

En relación a las reservas, supongamos que la secretaria, Betty Davis, de un alto ejecutivo, llamado William Johnson, hace una reserva de hotel **en lugar de** su jefe, es decir el alto ejecutivo no realiza la reserva sino su secretaria, pero el nombre que figura en dicha reserva es el del alto ejecutivo. El nombre William Johnson es el que aparece registrado en la base de datos del hotel, la reserva está **a su nombre**.

Comment: No, no soy angloparlante. Al mismo tiempo, gracias por compartir el vínculo a esta cadena en inglés. También era interesante.

Comment: Esto es correcto. Quería anotar que existe la alternativa de *«¿bajo que nombre está la reserva?»*